# Creating and using a large number of objects with a non-preset name in Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, tkinter

**What I`m using**: `Tkinter` lib, `setattr()` function

**What I want**: by using a `for` loop create some number of widgets with some parameters and roughly similar names. Then, I want to be able to set their location using the same loop

**How it looks for me for now**:

```
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
    Tk.__init__(self)
    for i in range(n):
        setattr(Label(self, text=f"name{i}", OTHER_OPTIONS), f"name{i}", _value)
        name{i}.place(y=0+10*i)
```

**What I expect to see**: a column of text from name0 to nameN with 10 units between each

**For what I need it?**: to create a function in which I can send parameters like name of object, text, background and other of label options

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making this more difficult than it needs to be. Just store the labels in a list or dictionary.

```
self.labels = []
for i in range(n):
    label = Label(self, ...)
    self.labels.append(label)
```

I also strongly recommend against `place`. It's much easier to create responsive applications using `pack` and `grid`. With `place` you have to a lot more work, and it's easy to create a UI that looks good only looks good for one specific configuration (resolution, default font, window size).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if I want to use `pack()`, then I need to write something like this: `self.labels[index].pack()`?

Comment: @SALOway: yeah, something like that would work if `index` is a valid index. In the code in this example you can do `label.pack(...)`.